# Get all nodes with the same name in different levels

Tags: java, xml, jdom, xmlnode

The following is my XML file:

```
<scenario>
  <negotiation>
    <type>auction</type>

    <agent>
      <type>UtilityCompany</type>
      <electricityPlan>
        <type>PlanUtility</type>
        <offeredEnergy>10</offeredEnergy>
        <duration>20</duration>
        <price>10</price>
        <role>
          <type>Seller</type>
        </role>
        <electricityOrder>
          <type>SalesOrder</type>
        </electricityOrder>
      </electricityPlan>
    </agent>

    <agent>
      <type>LargeCustomer</type>
      <electricityPlan>
        <type>LargecPlan</type>
        <requestedEnergy>100</requestedEnergy>
        <duration>20</duration>
        <price>10</price>
        <role>
          <type>Buyer</type>
        </role>
        <electricityOrder>
          <type>PurchaseOrder</type>
        </electricityOrder>
      </electricityPlan>
    </agent>

  </negotiation>
</scenario>
```

I need to know how to append all the values inside `<type></type>` tag into an `ArrayList`.

Something like the following:

```
Agent[0] = UtilityCompany
Agent[1] = LargeCustomer

electricityPlan[0] = PlanUtility
electricityPlan[1] = LargecPlan

role[0] = Seller
role[1] = Buyer
```

Can someone please provide some insight?

**UPDATED INFOMATION**

At the moment, I have this:

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

```
    File fXmlFile = new File("scenario.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("negotiation");
    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(0);
    NodeList negotiationList = element.getElementsByTagName("agent");
    for (int i = 0; i < negotiationList.getLength(); i++) {

    Element negotiationElement = (Element) negotiationList.item(i);


NodeList agent = negotiationElement.getElementsByTagName("type");
System.out.println(agent.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());

NodeList role = negotiationElement.getElementsByTagName("role");
Element roleline = (Element) role.item(0);
System.out.println(roleline.getElementsByTagName("type").item(0).getTextContent());
```

}

```
}

Output

UtilityCompany
Seller
LargeCustomer
Buyer
LargeCustomer
Buyer
```

LargeCustomer
   Buyer

But I dont know how to get the values from

```
      1.         <type>auction</type>

      2. <type>PlanUtility</type>  from ElectricityPlan tag.
```

Finally I found a Solution for that:

**THIS CODE WORKS FOR GETTING THE REQUESTED NODES**

I have a solution for that:

```
 public class ReadingXML {

static List<String> AuctionType = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> AgentType = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> PlanType = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> RoleType = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> OrderType = new ArrayList<String>();
static NodeList auction ;

 public List<List<String>> ReadingXML(String fileLocation) throws      
 ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

//File fXmlFile = new File("C:....location\\scenario.xml");

File fXmlFile = new File(fileLocation);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
List<List<String>> listOfLists = Lists.newArrayList();

    NodeList nodesScenario = doc.getElementsByTagName("scenario");
    Element element0 = (Element) nodesScenario.item(0);
    NodeList scenarioList = element0.getElementsByTagName("negotiation");

   for (int j = 0; j < scenarioList.getLength(); j++) 
     {
       Element scenarioElement = (Element) scenarioList.item(j);
       auction = scenarioElement.getElementsByTagName("type");
       System.out.println(auction.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
       AuctionType.add(auction.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent()); 
     }
    List<String> AuctionTypeFiltered = Lists.newArrayList(Sets.newHashSet(AuctionType));
    listOfLists.add(Lists.newArrayList(AuctionTypeFiltered));

NodeList nodesNegotiation = doc.getElementsByTagName("negotiation");
Element element = (Element) nodesNegotiation.item(0);
NodeList negotiationList = element.getElementsByTagName("agent"); 

for (int i = 0; i < negotiationList.getLength(); i++) 
 {
   Element negotiationElement = (Element) negotiationList.item(i);
   NodeList agent = negotiationElement.getElementsByTagName("type");
   System.out.println(agent.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
   AgentType.add(agent.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());

   NodeList nodesElectricityPlan = doc.getElementsByTagName("electricityPlan");
   Element element1 = (Element) nodesElectricityPlan.item(0);
   NodeList ElectricityPlanList = element1.getElementsByTagName("plan");

   for (int j = 0; j < ElectricityPlanList.getLength(); j++) 
    {
      Element electricityPlanElement = (Element) ElectricityPlanList.item(j);
      NodeList plan = electricityPlanElement.getElementsByTagName("type");
      System.out.println(plan.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
      PlanType.add(plan.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
    } 
    List<String> PlanTypeFiltered = Lists.newArrayList(Sets.newHashSet(PlanType));
    listOfLists.add(Lists.newArrayList(PlanTypeFiltered));

    NodeList role = negotiationElement.getElementsByTagName("role");
    Element roleline = (Element) role.item(0);
    System.out.println(roleline.getElementsByTagName("type").item(0).getTextContent());
    RoleType.add(roleline.getElementsByTagName("type").item(0).getTextContent());

    NodeList electricityorder = negotiationElement.getElementsByTagName("electricityOrder");
    Element electricityorderline = (Element) electricityorder.item(0);
    System.out.println(electricityorderline.getElementsByTagName("type").item(0).getTextContent());
    OrderType.add(electricityorderline.getElementsByTagName("type").item(0).getTextContent());
  }
   List<String> AgentTypeFiltered = Lists.newArrayList(Sets.newHashSet(AgentType));
   listOfLists.add(Lists.newArrayList(AgentTypeFiltered));

   List<String> RoleTypeFiltered = Lists.newArrayList(Sets.newHashSet(RoleType));
   listOfLists.add(Lists.newArrayList(RoleTypeFiltered));

   List<String> OrderTypeFiltered = Lists.newArrayList(Sets.newHashSet(OrderType));
   listOfLists.add(Lists.newArrayList(OrderTypeFiltered));

    return listOfLists;
    }



  }
```

Comment: You might need to use some xml parser libraries.Dom Parser, SAX parser, Stax parser are some of them.

Comment: Yes, I know, the problem is how I can get elements, first, I was parsing the xml file:  ....  dom = db.parse("file.xml")....; later I was parsing the document, but I was using :   NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("Agent");

Comment: What are you using to parse the XML? I'll write up an answer using whatever you're using.

Comment: I don't understand what's hard about this. Why can't you traverse the the dom and remember the parent element as you descend deeper? when you find a <type> you add the saved parent to the arrayList...?

Comment: @Calicoder difficult part for me is to get <type>auction</type> and  <type>PlanUtility</type>. Thanks

Comment: Since your `main` method is declared to throw XPathExpressionException, you seem to be at least aware of the existence of XPath.  Why not use it?  It would make this considerably easier.

Comment: @user1069571 hey I'm writing an answer, had to go to work yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having an `ArrayList` for each type consider taking the OO (Object Oriented) approach. You'll notice many advantages with this approach, like (a lot) fewer variables and lines of code. Take for instance the following:

**Driver.java :**

```
public class Driver {
    public static final String XML_FILE_PATH = "zin/zin.xml";

    /**
     * Entry point of the program.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JDOMException {
        File xmlFile = new File(XML_FILE_PATH);
        // the SAXBuilder is the easiest way to create the JDOM2 objects
        SAXBuilder jdomBuilder = new SAXBuilder();

        // jdomDocument is the JDOM2 Object
        Document jdomDocument = jdomBuilder.build(xmlFile);
        Element root = jdomDocument.getRootElement();
        Element negotiation = root.getChild("negotiation");

        // get the list of children agent elements
        List<Element> xmlAgents = negotiation.getChildren("agent");
        // list for holding the agent objects parsed from the XML file
        List<Agent> agents = new ArrayList<Agent>();

        // iterate over the agent nodes from the XML file and create
        // agent objects to represent them
        for (Element currentAgent : xmlAgents) {
            Agent newAgent = new Agent();
            // set the new agent's 'AgentType' before descending into
            // the children XML nodes
            newAgent.setAgentType(currentAgent.getChildText("type"));

            // recursively finish the new agent
            descend(currentAgent, newAgent);

            // add the new agent to the ArrayList of agents
            agents.add(newAgent);
        }

        // print agent data to output
        for(Agent agent : agents) {
            System.out.println(agent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Note: Agent is not immutable, this method alters the members
     * of the passed in Agent object.
     * 
     * Recursive method to fill in the rest of a passed in Agent object.
     * 
     * @param ele - an XML element to descend.
     * @param agent - the Agent object to finish filling.
     */
    public static void descend(Element ele, Agent agent) {
        for (Element e : ele.getChildren()) {
            switch (e.getName()) {
                case "electricityPlan":
                    agent.setPlanType(e.getChildText("type"));
                    break;
                case "role":
                    agent.setRoleType(e.getChildText("type"));
                    break;
                case "electricityOrder":
                    agent.setOrderType(e.getChildText("type"));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            descend(e, agent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Agent.java**

```
public class Agent {
    private String auctionType;
    private String agentType;
    private String planType;
    private String roleType;
    private String orderType;

    public Agent() {
        auctionType = "";
        agentType = "";
        planType = "";
        roleType = "";
        orderType = "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "Agent\r\n";

        str += "  AuctionType: " + getAuctionType() + "\r\n";
        str += "    AgentType: " + getAgentType() + "\r\n";
        str += "     RoleType: " + getRoleType() + "\r\n";
        str += "     PlanType: " + getPlanType() + "\r\n";
        str += "    OrderType: " + getOrderType();

        return str;
    }

    public String getAuctionType() {
        return auctionType;
    }

    public void setAuctionType(String auctionType) {
        this.auctionType = auctionType;
    }

    public String getAgentType() {
        return agentType;
    }

    public void setAgentType(String agentType) {
        this.agentType = agentType;
    }

    public String getPlanType() {
        return planType;
    }

    public void setPlanType(String planType) {
        this.planType = planType;
    }

    public String getRoleType() {
        return roleType;
    }

    public void setRoleType(String roleType) {
        this.roleType = roleType;
    }

    public String getOrderType() {
        return orderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(String orderType) {
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

}
```

Running Driver's `main` method outputs the following:

```
Agent
  AuctionType: 
    AgentType: UtilityCompany
     RoleType: Seller
     PlanType: PlanUtility
    OrderType: SalesOrder
Agent
  AuctionType: 
    AgentType: LargeCustomer
     RoleType: Buyer
     PlanType: LargecPlan
    OrderType: PurchaseOrder
```

---

Of course the above code is just an example. The `Agent` class doesn't necessarily need to have all of those accessors and mutators, or any at all, its members could all be public or protected. The point is that you can have a list of agents, with each agent object containing members for each type, rather than a list per type with each index representing a different agent.